# tomcat automatically binds it to 0.0.0.0 from 127.0.0.1

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, tomcat6, apr

I have made a port( example 1234) to be bound to the local host 127.0.0.1 .But when i restart tomcat automatically binds it to 0.0.0.0 .

And my connector in server.xml contains 127.0.0.1 as address .

My Tomcat Version

- Server version: Apache Tomcat/6.0.48 Server
- built:   Dec 12 2016 14:06:06 UTC
- Server number:  6.0.48.0 OS
- Name:        Linux JVM
- Version:    1.8.0_111-b15
- JVM Vendor:     Oracle Corporation

Logs in Tomcat

- May 03, 2017 1:58:19 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol destroy
  INFO: Stopping Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-127.0.0.1-1234
- ...........
  ...........
- May 03, 2017 1:58:49 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol init
  INFO: Initializing Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-0.0.0.0-1234

Below is the netstat details

- tcp   0   0   0.0.0.0:1234    0.0.0.0:*   LISTEN

Can some one say why this issue is happening ?

Comment: Share `server.xml`. Don't use that Tomcat version, it is horribly old.

Comment: Define 'I have made a port'. Off topic.

Comment: I have configured my connector in server.xml in such a way that port 1234 is accessible only in localhost .

Comment: Server.xml
<Connector server="myserver" URIEncoding="UTF-8" port="1234" address="127.0.0.1" protocol="HTTP/1.1"  .. .>